# ¿Cómo representar HTML que tengo en mi base de datos mysql?

Tags: html, pdo

En mi base de datos tengo registros tipo:

```
Primer parrafo.<div><br></div><div>Segundo parrafo.</div>
```

¿Cómo representar en mi interfaz esos párrafos con el HTML que tengo en mi base de datos? En este momento hago:

```
$last_product = $pdo->prepare("
     SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1
     ORDER BY product_insert_date DESC
     LIMIT 1");
     $last_question->execute();
     $result = $last_question->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     foreach ($result as $row){
         echo $new_body = $row -> product_description;
     }
```

Me devuelve esto tal cual: `Primer parrafo.<div><br></div><div>Segundo parrafo.</div>` y el resultado esperado es:

```
Primer parrafo.

Segundo parrafo.
```

Comment: No termino de entender ¿Cual sería el resultado esperado?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, he editado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row -> product_description));
```